# wrong data shows in combobox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Kendo ComboBox.in mvc4.
and bind it to database.

my code:

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("id_team").BindTo(Model.tbl_team.Select(c=>new SelectListItem{Text = c.team, Value = c.id.ToString()}));
```

but below cods shows in my combobox:

```
Select Team:
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field id_team must be a number." id="id_team" name="id_team" type="text"/> <script> jQuery(function(){jQuery("#id_team").kendoDropDownList({"dataSource":[{"Text":"Barcelona","Value":"1"},{"Text":"manchester united","Value":"2"}],"dataTextField":"Text","dataValueField":"Value"});});
```

why?

Comment: Do you have js errors on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is in empty drop-down list, and the most likely reason is in required js miss. Please make sure you have referenced all the scripts from Kendo introduction page: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction

Comment: no , i use this codes in head :<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css")">

     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>

Comment: there is no one to help me?